# UIPanGestureRecognizer: Offset view under finger

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a scrollView with some UIViews as subviews that I drag around. The problem is that the subviews is rather small, and when dragging them, you can't see them because the finger is in the way.

How do I offset the view a little bit upwards while dragging?

Thanks

```
if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
{
    CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self];
    draggingView.center = CGPointMake(draggingView.center.x + translation.x,
                                      draggingView.center.y + translation.y);

    [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:self];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code
 `CGPoint touchPoint = [recognizer locationInView:self];`
try changing touchPoint